my java service old generation usage is always 100% when i use zgc
I upgraded the JDK version of my Java service to Java 21 and change the garbage collector from G1 to ZGC. Here are my startup parameters:
-XX:+UseZGC -XX:+ZGenerational
Then I use the jstat -gcutil command to observe the GC status of the service, and I find that the old generation usage is always 100%.
The output result is as follows, I found that "O" has always been 100%. Why?
 S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT     FGC    FGCT     CGC    CGCT       GCT   
     -      -  72.73 100.00  98.83  92.81   7782     0.278     -         - 10955     0.309     0.586
     -      -  72.73 100.00  98.83  92.81   7782     0.278     -         - 10955     0.309     0.586

I searched a lot of information, but I couldn't find the reason, and my service is also running normally now.

What (type of) program are you running and what load does it process? Do you experience the same for other loads or programs?

Looking at The Z Garbage Collector, it might have to do with its uncommit behaviour. What happens if you also specify -XX:-ZUncommit?

Are you noticing any issues in the behaviour of the application at execution time?
